# How to get smooth lines when saving canvas pic (python)?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When drawing on the canvas (tkinter), the lines look connected and alright but when looking at them after saving the drawing on the computer as png file they suddenly are not.

[image: Expected image]

[image: Saved image]

This is the code I use for drawing the lines:

```
self.canvas.create_line((self.x, self.y, event.x, event.y), fill=self.pcolor,width=self.pen_size,capstyle="round")
self.draw.line([(self.x,self.y),(event.x,event.y)],fill=self.pcolor,width=self.pen_size,joint="curve")
self.x, self.y = event.x, event.y
```

And this is the code I use to save the drawings as images:

```
image=None
my_image=im.new("RGB",(990,530),(255,255,255))
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)  #all three are class variables
 
def save_pic(self,event=None):
    my_file=asksaveasfile(mode="w",defaultextension=".png",filetypes=[("png files","*.png")],initialdir="/home/hale/",parent=window)
    if my_file is not None:
        path=os.path.abspath(my_file.name)
        self.my_image.save(path)
```

Besides, adding `smooth=True` to `self.canvas.create_line()` does not make any difference. How do I make the lines smoother and connected as in the first image?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you could also share the code that you use to save the canvas

Comment: It is the issue on `ImageDraw` module, not `Canvas` widget.  You may just grab the snapshot of the canvas instead of using `ImageDraw`.

Comment: @acw1668 I have tried using ImageGrab before but it didn't work. I suspect it is because I use linux but I don't know for sure.